# Debugging SQL Server stored procedure from VS2019 IDE

Tags: sql-server

We know that SSMS version 18.4 no longer supports stored procedure debugging. So I install VS 2019 Community Edition.

My database resides in different PCs which I am accessing over VPN. When I connect to SQL Server by VS 2019 then it could connect but when I try to debug a stored procedure then I get this message:

[image]

I do not understand how to overcome this problem. I login with SA credentials. In which PC the firewall blocking in my PC firewall or remote PC firewall on which database reside?

Again I download dbforge SQL Complete 6.4 here is the link https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/download.html?_ga=2.16547893.2044381386.1585764902-355709400.1585764902

Which is a add-ins for SQL Server. When I try to debug stored procedure by dbforge SQL Complete 6.4 then I get this error message:

> Unable to attach the Transact-SQL debugger. Make sure you have met the following requirements:
>
> - Debugging firewall exceptions on the client and server sides are enabled.
> - Your login is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.
> - Your database is not in the single-user mode.

So please guide me how to overcome this problem?